# Is it possible for jQuery Mobile to show the hash in the first page it loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-mobile, hashtag

If I have an `index.html` file and it contains multiple pages. When I load the page, I want the URL to contain the hash `#first`, aka `index.html#first`. Instead, the URL says `index.html`.

My work around so far to is to have a fake first page and then link directly to `index.html#first`, hopefully never showing the "real" first page, aka `index.html#fake`.

Is there a better way of doing this?

```
<body>

    <!--
        fake page
    -->
    <div data-role="page" id="fake">
        <div data-role="content">
            fake
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--
        first
    -->
    <div data-role="page" id="first">
        <div data-role="content">
            first
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--
        second
    -->
    <div data-role="page" id="second">
        <div data-role="content">
            second
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Is it ok to put the fake page behing first page & never refer it? will that work? or it has to be on top section of your body?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you check in JS if the hash code is present on index.html page and if it's not then you can redirect the browser to `index.html#first`

```
$(function () {
    if (window.location.hash.length == 0) {
        window.location = window.location.href + '#first';    
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Configure your web server so requests for "index.html" *and* requests for '/' (path with no file!) return a `301 Moved Permanently` response to redirect to 'index.html#first'

That said, I can't imagine why you want to force the hash onto the url; maybe a library that's not robust enough?  Correctly coded, `http://example.com/` , `http://example.com/index.html` , and `http://example.com/index.html#first` can and should (IMHO) all behave the same.